# "So I told a porcupine..."

Tags: etymology

I heard this phrase spoken on a British TV show. It was obvious from context that it meant 'a little white lie'.

How did this colloquialism arise? I have my own theory about about how this may have derived from Cockney rhyming slang, but I am more interested in the correct background.

@Dancrumb It was an episode of "Inspector Lewis". I can't place the exact episode, but Lewis was leaning on a newspaper reporter he had caught in a lie. The lie had been to cover up his infidelity, not relevant to the case and he stated to the Inspector...

Comment: It has negligible currency. It's an allusion to ***porkie = pork pie*** (Cockney rhyming slang for ***lie***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would suggest re-posting your comment as an answer. It seems sufficient to me.

Comment: Which show? It's not just idle curiosity... some shows delight in creating new phrases

Comment: I'm guessing that it may actually have been "porkie" or "pork pie", misheard...

Comment: Agree with the above - sometimes people say "porkie pie", which could very easily have been misheard.

Answer (score 1):

Rhyming slang - Pork pie - lie. Telling a porky: lying.
Telling a Porcupine - English labored humor.
Not researched only opined.